# Show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}): \mathbb{Q}$ is normal.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

**My Attempt**: Let $\gamma_0=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}, \gamma_1=-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}, \gamma_2=\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}, \gamma_3=-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}$. Let $L=\mathbb{Q}(\gamma_0, \gamma_1, \gamma_2, \gamma_3)$ and $M=\mathbb{Q}(\gamma_0)$. Then clearly $L$ is the splitting field of $f(t)=t^4-4t^2+2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, hence $L: \mathbb{Q}$ is normal. Clearly $L: \mathbb{Q}$ is also finite, hence if we can show that $M^*$-the group of all $M$-automorphisms of L-is a normal subgroup of the Galois Group $G$ of $L$, then we can conclude that $M: \mathbb{Q}$ is normal by the *Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory*.

Suppose $\tau\in G$. We wish to show that $\tau M^* \tau^{-1}\subset M^*$.

**Proof**:

Suppose $\sigma\in M^*$. We want to show that $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1}$ is a $M$-automorphism of L.

Clearly $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1}$ is an automorphism of L.

Suppose $x\in M$, then $x=\frac{p+q\gamma_0+r\sqrt{2}}{a+b\gamma_0+c\sqrt{2}}$, where $p, q, r, a, b, c \in \mathbb{Q}$. We want to show that $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1}(x)=x$. **Dead end**.

I then tried to apply the following Lemma:

"If $L: K$ is a field extension, $M$ is an intermediate field, and $\tau$ is a $K$-automorphism of L, then $\tau(M)^*=\tau M^*\tau^{-1}$".

If I can show that $M\subset\tau(M)$, then we'd have $\tau(M)^*\subset M^*$, and then we'd have $\tau M^*\tau^{-1}=\tau(M)^*\subset M^*$ by the lemma. This approach failed as well.

Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Normal extension iff splitting Field of some polynomial.

Comment: Can you observe that $L=M$? Now prove it.

Comment: Another hint: $\sqrt{2+\sqrt 2}\cdot \sqrt{2-\sqrt 2} = \sqrt 2 \in M$. How does that help in proving $L=M$?

Comment: I cracked it-thank you so much everybody!